# What sys.sp_addextendedproperty doing?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, system-stored-procedures

I am deleteing one month data from  table tbl_testrecord (diagrev is one of the colume )in test database now .And i will going to do same in Production database. When i am comparing script of the same table in test database and production database, I can see this code in test database and not in production

```
 EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_DescriptionN',       @value=N'diagrev' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'tbl_testrecord', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'diagrev'
```

What exactly this addextendedproperty SP doing? is it going to crash my delete script?
Please advice !!

Comment: How were you generating the script?  All that does is set the value of an extended property (Description) to the table.  Should be safe to ignore, assuming you don't have code that tries to query the description (which would be unusual)

Comment: Are you deleting _rows_ or a _column_?

Comment: @DStanley , the table as already there .i am comparing script from script table as>>create to>>New quary editer window .. and i am deleting rows only..

Comment: OK I guess I'm confused why you need a `CREATE TABLE` script if you are deleting rows from an existing table.

Comment: Someone probably gave the table a description in the designer in test but not in production.

Comment: @D stanley , from the SP defination i dont think its will create any problem for delete , but this table is one of the main table of my applicatin so i want be carefull with this, and one more thing is where i am puting my delete script in one existing SP which  have lots of other BL , if my delete script breack it will be big pain for me.